# Python loop through single cell and column in a csv

Tags: python, pandas, iterator, iteration

I have just picked up python and I am trying to use the module fuzzwuzzy in tandem with pandas to assist in matching names from PLACEMENT and CREATIVE_NAME columns.

I have figured out how to test the first row of PLACEMENT against all rows of CREATIVE_NAME; however, I cannot figure out how to move to the next row of PLACEMENT and test against the CREATIVE_NAME column.

My eventual goal of the project is for the top match(s) for each PLACEMENT value to be printed out for further analysis.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
fp = df["PLACEMENT"]
tp = df["CREATIVE_NAME"]

score = 0
x=0
y=0
import csv
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for column in reader:
        if score == 0:
            score += fuzz.ratio(fp[x],tp[y])
            if score > 95:
                print "The score is %d"", We have a match!" %(score)
            elif score > 70:
                print "The score is %d"", We have a high likelihood of a match!" %(score)
            elif score > 50:
                print "The score is %d"", The match is not likely!" %(score)
            else:
                print "The score is only %d"", This is not a match!" %(score)
            y += 1
            score = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to match all entries in the placement column against all entries in the creative name column.  This can be done by a nested loop:  for each placement, for each creative name, compare the placement and the creative name.

The FuzzyWuzzy library has a convenience function that can be used to replace the inner loop by a single function call that extracts the best matches:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

for placement in fp:
    best_matches = process.extract(placement, tp, limit=3)
    print placement, best_matches
```

Be warned though that this will need *n*² comparisons, where *n* is the number of rows in your data set.  Depending on the size of the data set, this might take a long time.

Note that you don't need to open the file after reading the data set into memory via pandas.  Your loop over the reopened file doesn't make any use of the `column` loop variable (which should be called `row`, by the way).

Comment: Thank you, the code works perfectly! Your feedback is greatly appreciated. And yes, I have roughly 15,000 rows of each column. I am going to need to find a way to subset the data first. 5 rows have taken nearly 20 minutes.